# How to send array of objects within request body in JSON format via Postman?

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, postman

I want to test my API function by sending array of objects via postman 
When I send my request in JSON format to the function and then looping through the array to access each object property it gives me the following error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cN3bY.jpg

Here is my request:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOjkr.jpg

I searched how to send an array of objects using postman and found that I am doing it the right way 
I selected row under body section so I can add my request body and selected it's format as JSON and added "Content-Type: application/json" to the request header

My API function:

```
public function createRetailer(Request $request){
    $machines = $request->machineInfo;

    foreach($machines as $machine){
        $newMachine = new Machine;
        $newMachine->machine_no = $machine->machineNo;
        $newMachine->account_type = $machine->accountType;
        $newMachine->machine_type = $machine->machineType;
        $newMachine->retialer_id = $retailer->retailerId;
        $newMachine->save();
    }
}
```

I expect that i can access each array object properties as a PHP object but I found that it is not an object by testing it using is_object() function:

```
public function createRetailer(Request $request){
    $machines = $request->machineInfo;

    foreach($machines as $machine){
        return response()->json(is_object($machine));
    }
}
```

I do not know if the problem is within my request or something that I might misunderstand while retrieving data of the request in my controller function

Comment: Can you add a `return dd($request->machineInfo)` at the top of your method for debug ? As a guess, I think you should either `json_decode()` every element of your array, or access its attributes as an array `$machine['machineNo']`

Comment: The response is array of arrays:    ```array:1 [
  0 => array:4 [
    "machineNo" => "123456"
    "accountType" => "Paid"
    "machineType" => "hb3br238rhi"
    "retailerId" => "1"
  ]
]```  When I try to use json_decode() it responds with error: **json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either it is an array and in that case, you can call

```
$object = (object) $machine;
```

Or it is a string aka JSON, you can call

```
$object = json_decode($machine);
```

Or if it is an object/array use

```
$machine['machineType'];
```

Also please add a dump of the $machine var

EDIT

Try sending the request not using [] because they will be converted into an array with objects in it, instead, if you remove the [] and only have {} it should only be one object in the request

```
"machineInfo" : {
    "machineNo" : "1123213",
    "accountType" : "Paid",
    //...rest here..
}
```

Try this:

```
 public function createRetailer(Request $request){
    $machines = $request->machineInfo;

    foreach($machines as $machine){
        $object = (object) $machine;
        return response()->json(is_object($object));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the last option is accepted but I do not get it I think in that case syntax looks like am dealing with an array not an object although in the request I sent it as object

Comment: @KareemSaeed updated answer think it is because you are wrapping the object in [] which becomes one object in an array instead of just one object, therefore when the request is received it is an array and not an object

Comment: I want it to be an array of objects not only a single object

Comment: @KareemSaeed kind of guessing without a dump of  $request->machineInfo; and one iteration of $machine; but updated answer with what I think the problem is..

Comment: I think to deal with each array variable as an object not array your last answer is the most accepted one

Answer (score 0):

Since your request sends data as an array, you can access the elements as so :

```php
public function createRetailer(Request $request){
    $machines = $request->machineInfo;

    foreach($machines as $machine){
        $newMachine = new Machine;
        $newMachine->machine_no = $machine['machineNo'];
        $newMachine->account_type = $machine['accountType'];
        $newMachine->machine_type = $machine->['machineType'];
        $newMachine->retialer_id = $retailer->['retailerId'];
        $newMachine->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: why it sends data in array although the request is written as array of objects?

Comment: Your array of objects is parsed by Laravel as an array of arrays, with a key/value mapping, using it as mentioned above provides the needed behavior and you can access the data of each attribute of each `$machine` as an array. if you want to have it as an object, you could simply add `json_encode($machine)` inside your loop.